# tesseract output is different from input image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tesseract

I am performing ocr on cropped images, using tesseract and pytesseract(in python). One of cropped images are are of date format in `dd/mm/yyyy`. The output text I am getting is `dd,/mm,/yyyy`. What is the reason behind this? How to get to improve that ocr quality?

I have already done some preprocessing on the cropped images, including padding, morphological transformation(kernel = ellipse).

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel1)
div = np.float32(gray)/(close)
res = np.uint8(cv2.normalize(div,div,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, lang='eng', config=config)
```

[Input Image : 18/05/1997](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Rut.png)

output text : 18,/05,/1997

expected text : 18/05/1997

Comment: Isn't it recognized as 3 strings: "18", "/05", "/1997"? What's your config? Have you tried changing [--psm](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#user-content-options)?

Comment: no it is recognized as "18,/05,/1997". I have tried psm-0 and 6, I dont think psm will have an effect on this as it is a cropped image

Comment: config is -oem 2 -psm 0. I have also tried -oem 2 psm 6

Comment: I'd try with --psm 8 (Treat the image as a single word)

Comment: It is treating at as a single word only as the output is only one string

Comment: tried psm 8 too. no change

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tesseract 4.x, use trainneddata from [tessdata_best](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best):

```
$ tesseract z9Rut.png - --dpi 300
18/05/1981
```